# Exam Question: No sooner ____ the destruction completed

Tags: verbs, exam-questions

> A) No sooner **had** the destruction completed, than mother walked in.
>
> B) No sooner **did** the destruction **complete**, than mother walked in.
>
> C) No sooner **had** the destruction **been** completed, than mother walked in.
>
> D) No sooner **was** the destruction completed, than mother walked in.

Which is the best sentence among the four given options? I know its against SE's rule to ask a question without  mentioning the research done on my part or not mentioning the reason / point of confusion or not pouring in enough details regarding question but I am sorry here I really don't have any idea  what to write.

This is a question asked in my exam in which I have to choose the best sentence and to my ears except option 3 all *sound* fine.

Comment: None of them are good English, but all are *possible* (with some editing).  It seems to me that they're testing you with obscure and specious "rules" of English grammar to see if you can memorize the patterns they teach, rather than focusing on what is *natural*.  These examples were likely not written by a native.

Comment: @Andrew Yes you are right, they aren't written by a native speaker and they all may not be good English but which is the best option to choose from these four ?

Comment: As far as details go, there are some thing you can do to make this a better question. For example, what book did this come out of? Are they testing comprehension of a certain section or chapter? Or is it a practice exam for a test? That kind of knowledge helps a native speaker get a better grasp of the situation; without it, most of us are left scratching our heads, as @Andrew was.

Comment: Options A and B are incorrect because they make the destruction an agent. What did the destruction complete? Option C is grammatical correct, though it implies that the destruction was a deliberate act. Option D does not name an agent of the destruction.

Comment: @user212388  I couldn't pick any of the answers as definitively "correct", so I'd be forced to pick one at random.  The problem is the noun "destruction", which sounds weird when combined with "complete", no matter which verb tense you choose.  They're all equally unfamiliar -- but if I were to read these in a children's book written 100 years ago, I'd roll with it and move on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the examples given are ungrammatical to the extent that the question (which one is correct) cannot be answered.

Comment: For an explanation of the "no sooner than" figure of speech, see [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/46920/6700).

Comment: @DavidC Thankyou, it helped a lot to figure out the differences in meaning of these sentences, now i can judge that option A and B are certainly wrong to choose here but can you please shed a little more light on the meaning of option C and D.

Comment: Looking more carefully I see that both C and D portray the destruction as a task which was "completed". Someone started the destruction and had it finished just before mother came in. If instead the destruction "just happened" say "the destruction was complete".

Comment: To further illustrate the meaning of C or D: "No sooner had the destruction been completed, than mother walked in and said, 'You knocked down the wrong wall!'" Contrast this with "The dishes fell one after another with resounding crashes. No sooner was the destruction complete, than mother walked in and said, 'I should know better than to leave you boys alone.'"

Comment: It is impossible to discern what a non-English-speaking teacher may imagine to be correct or incorrect "English". This is an unfortunate problem for the student, and one that we face with some frequency here. The best we could do is to tell you which option is least flawed. My _guess_ is that your teacher imagines that **C** is "best".

Answer (score 1):

You generally do not use "had" or "had ... been" with "No sooner ... than". It is usually "No sooner did ... than so-and-so." But that doesn't eliminate the possibility of the fourth option of using "was". However, if you were to choose one, I'd say the sentence would be: "No sooner DID the destruction complete, than mother walked in."

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* these are correct; answers without explanation don't help someone learn the language. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.

Comment: @SallyHope In the above comments David mentioned option A and B make the destruction as an agent, so going by that isn't the choice suggested by you wrong ?